# what is the benifit of using woff font file

Tags: css, woff

I saw example of a site which is using a separate font file (woff) and using the source code as

```
<span id="txt44_1109014" data-width="147.274994" style="left:
58.538px; top: 23.413px; letter-spacing: -0.596739391304348px;">®euee&nbsp;Deelee&nbsp;DeeHeCe&nbsp;³ee</span>
```

Below are the CSS for this element

```
#txt44_1109014, #txt45_1109014, #txt46_1109014 {
  font-family: fnt0;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 29px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}
```

In the source code I saw there is a .woff font file which is coming from network(server).
I want to know what is this method(any specific name)?
We can do same thing via usign unicodes still what is the benific of this?
Any standard document for this present on net?

Comment: different browsers use different font file extension so you also need that type of font.

Comment: check this once http://www.w3.org/Fonts/WOFF-FAQ#What_are_the_benefits_of_using_WOFF

Comment: Using it without any additional type is very cross browser compatible : http://caniuse.com/woff.